# Regular expression in grep that match string

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have strings that looks like:

```
sapaa-czbrqrnop-3449607e001
sapaa-deduipswp-3446871e001
sapaa-delejwtbp2-3446869e001
```

These strings are in files on server. I would like to use a grep a find this strings. So I wrote something like this:

```
grep "[a-zA-Z]\-[a-zA-Z0-9]\-[0-9]\e[0-9]" filename
```

So it should find appropriate strings on lines. But it doesn't work. I am on the rocks. Is there anything wrong with this regular expression or I can not use it this way in grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `\+` or `*` next to each character classes. `+` repeats the previous token one or more times, whereas your character class `[a-zA-Z]` without following `*` or `+` would match a single character. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times. Because basic grep uses BRE , you need to escape the `+` symbol. So that it would act like a repeatation quantifier.

```
grep "[a-zA-Z]\+-[a-zA-Z0-9]\+-[0-9]\+e[0-9]\+" filename
```

Use anchors if necessary.

```
grep "^[a-zA-Z]\+-[a-zA-Z0-9]\+-[0-9]\+e[0-9]\+$" filename
```

Comment: what does the +$ indicates?